# How to properly format a class instance reference

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have this piece of documentation:

```
 /**
 * This method creates an import job for the given @arg item
 *
 * The default implementation should be suitable for most needs,
 * it'll create an instance of @class ImportProjectJob
 *
 * @return a job that imports the project
 */
virtual KJob* createImportJob(ProjectFolderItem* item);
```

However `@class` is not meant to be used like this and there is nothing like `@instanceof` in doxygen.
How should I format this?

Comment: `@arg`, `@class`, `@fn` and alike are not meant as semantic annotations but to tell Doxygen to start a special section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Doxygen's [automatic link generation rules](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html), if some documentation text matches the name of a class which has been documented, and that text uses interCaps naming style, then Doxygen will automatically transform that text into a link to that documentation page. So if you just use "ImportProjectJob", Doxygen will find that class (if it has been documented) and transform that text into a link to it.

But if your class/function doesn't use interCaps naming, you can explicitly link to a documented entity via `@ref`:

```
 * The default implementation should be suitable for most needs,
 * it'll create an instance of @ref ImportProjectJob
```

---

FYI: `@arg` is meant for starting a list of function parameter definitions. Something like:

```
@arg @c AlignLeft left alignment.
@arg @c AlignCenter center alignment.
@arg @c AlignRight right alignment
```

What you're looking for is `@p`, which is inline formatting for referencing parameter names and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@ref` instead of `@class` and document the class where it is declared.

Usually (as by default, i.e. when [`AUTOLINK_SUPPORT`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_autolink_support) is `YES`), it is not even necessary to explicitly reference it. Doxygen will link it automatically when it detects the name.

By the way, your use of `@arg` is not as expected. Use `@p` for inline reference and [`@param`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam) for documenting method arguments.

---

```
 /**
  * @brief This method creates an import job for the given @p item
  *
  * @details The default implementation should be suitable for most needs,
  *   it'll create an instance of ImportProjectJob
  *
  * @param item this is a folder item
  *
  * @return a job that imports the project
  */
 virtual KJob* createImportJob(ProjectFolderItem* item);
```

and this is where `ImportProjectJob` is declared:

```
 /**
  * @brief short desc of the class
  * 
  * @details A long description
  */
 class ImportProjectJob : public KJob
 {};
```